# Apending variable in Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have this selector

```
self = $('.trim .person:nth-child('+index+')');
self.append('<img src="'+element.profilePic+'" class="profilePic" />');
```

I then want to use this select a class within

```
  $(self + '.spacer').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

I also tried

```
self + $('.spacer').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it as the [context parameter in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
$('.spacer', self).css('opacity', 0.5);
```

---

Or use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get element within the current jQuery object.

```
self.find('.spacer').css('opacity', 0.5);
```